# Global Availability of Connection String

Tags: asp.net

I have one website which is developed in classic asp, asp.net, java etc.
in classic asp i created global.asa to access application variables which hold the details of connection-string. global.asa file is available in wwwroot.
in the same way i wanted to have application variables for asp.net web-applications, I have n number of web-application in different directories ,currently i am using connection string from web.config file for each web-application ,
how do i  make centralized or global availability of connection string

Answer (score 0):

You can use global.asax in ASP.Net to store it as application variable though I would have to say that its not the best way to store connection string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf(v=vs.90).aspx